# How to replace & and space from a string Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to replace '&' and 'space' from a string.

I can remove the space by `string.replace(/[\s]/g, '');`

and remove the special character & by `string.replace(/[^\da-zA-Z]/g, '')`

Can I use both regex in one code? for removing special charecters and space from the string.

Comment: You are removing all special characters, not just `&`...

Comment: It sounds a little like you're trying to encode a value to place it in the querystring, if so try using `encodeURIComponent()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `|` to "or" regexes, e.g.

```
/(\s|&)/g
```

Grouping via `(...)` *can* be necessary to scope what gets or'd.

In this case, you just have two selectors, so it should work without as well.

```
/\s|&/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you don't want to use regex.

```js
var str = "abc def & ghi jkl & mno";
console.log(str.split(' ').join('').split('&').join(''));
```

first replace space with null and than replace '&' with null.

It might be help you.

Answer (score 1):

Combine regex for & and space `/[& ]+/g`

```js
var str='abzx12&  1'
console.log(str.replace(/[& ]+/g,''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with one more solution

```
.replace(/ |&/g,'')
```

Example

```js
var a = "asdasdas dsadasdas dasdas asdas & dasdasd &&&&";
console.log(a.replace(/ |&/g,''));
```